# how to append web service json data every time when function is called using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, web-services

Here i am calling function getData at every second all is happning good   except appending. 
every time when function is calling the angularjs is replacing old data to new data.
 but i want to append after existing data. any one plz help.

```
     <div ng-app="serviceConsumer">
     <div ng-controller="questionsController">
    <div ng-repeat="j in LiveChat">
    <div>
    <div>{{j.UserName2}}</div>
    <div>
    <div>{{j.Text2}}<div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('serviceConsumer', []);
    app.controller('questionsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/GetUserDataWebServices.asmx/GetLiveChatListData",
                params: {
                    username: $('.ExeCutiveName').text()
                }
            })
             .success(function (data) {
                 var myjson = JSON.parse(data);
                 $scope.LiveChat = JSON.parse(myjson);
                 //here i want to append myjson to existing ng-repeat <div>
             });
        }
    )};
    setInterval($scope.getData, 1000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concat data instead re-assigned it

Like this

```
$scope.LiveChat = $scope.LiveChat.concat(JSON.parse(myjson));
```

Comment: hi..Anik here i have to use two function, one for page load and one for setInterval(). is there any way to use both "$scope.LiveChat = JSON.parse(myjson);" and " $scope.LiveChat = $scope.LiveChat.concat(JSON.parse(myjson));" in same function

Comment: yes you can .. just check whether there is data in LiveChat  or not.. Like this `if($scope.LiveChat.length>0) $scope.LiveChat = $scope.LiveChat.concat(JSON.parse(myjson)); else $scope.LiveChat = JSON.parse(myjson);`

Comment: or You can user ternary like this `$scope.LiveChat = $scope.LiveChat.length >0 ? $scope.LiveChat.concat(JSON.parse(myjson)) : JSON.parse(myjson);`  @Nitesh

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `push` method

like `$scope.LiveChat.push(JSON.parse(myjson));`

Comment: op is getting list not  single object. If you push list into another list it'll push the pushed list into a index instead merging it.